# Linq SQL Search - From tags with more matches

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm writing a tag search in C# MVC, but I'm only able to get all the results that have one of the words. - The output should be only where all the input words matches, and exclude if e.g. 2 words are in the input, but only one of them matches.

My code so far:

```
List<String> list = Request["tags"].Split(' ').ToList();
KDBEntities q = new KDBEntities();

var query = (from tag in q.KDB_tags join question in q.KDB_questions on tag.question_id equals question.id where list.Any(x => x.Equals(tag.tag)) select question);
var Rquery = query.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();


return View(Rquery);
```

I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while, but with no luck.

Hope this makes sense, and any of you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried to use All instead of Any?

Comment: Yes - When using All instead of Any, I'm not getting any results if inputting more than 1 word.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the model of KDB_questions and KDB_tags.

Comment: They're both MSSQL Tables. - KDB_tags is 3 columns; id, question_id, tag - Each tag is inserted into the table as a new row.

Comment: What is `q`? Or: what type of LINQ is this? And can you show the classes? There should be navigation properties in there.

Comment: Okay so what if you get incoming tags as Tag1, Tag2 and Tag3, and you have 2 questions where one question has Tag1, Tag2, Tag3 and the other question has Tag1 and Tag2. Would you want both of the questions returned?

Comment: No, then only the one with all 3 tags should be returned. - But if I have Tag1 and Tag2 as incoming tag, I want both returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags list:

```
List<TagObj> tags = new List<TagObj>()
{
    new TagObj() { Id = 1, QuestionId = 1, Tag = "news" },
    new TagObj() { Id = 2, QuestionId = 1, Tag = "sports" },
    new TagObj() { Id = 3, QuestionId = 1, Tag = "famous" },
    new TagObj() { Id = 4, QuestionId = 2, Tag = "news" },
    new TagObj() { Id = 5, QuestionId = 2, Tag = "sports" },
    new TagObj() { Id = 6, QuestionId = 3, Tag = "news" },
    new TagObj() { Id = 7, QuestionId = 4, Tag = "funny" },
};
```

Questions list:

```
List<QuestionObj> questions = new List<QuestionObj>()
{
    new QuestionObj(){ QuestionId = 1, Question = "Whats up footballers?" },
    new QuestionObj(){ QuestionId = 2, Question = "These are famous news?" },
    new QuestionObj(){ QuestionId = 3, Question = "Read all about it?" },
    new QuestionObj(){ QuestionId = 4, Question = "You know whats funny?" }
};
```

These are incoming tags from the request:

```
var incomingTags = new List<string>() { "news", "sports" };
```

These are the queries:

```
    var query = from t in tags
                join q in questions on t.QuestionId equals q.QuestionId
                where incomingTags.Contains(t.Tag)
                select new { question = q, tag = t };

    var result = query.
        GroupBy(g => g.question.QuestionId).
        Where(g => g.ToList().Select(l => l.tag.Tag).SequenceEqual(incomingTags)).
        Select(s => s.First().question).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error to the result variable when executing; System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SequenceEqual[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Aaaah yes. I think this is just Linq2Objects method so it doesnt translate well to Linq2Entites. In the second query start of by var result = query.ToList()....